# Rails 5 - Doorkeeper token create ( ArgumentError )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, doorkeeper

Currently, I'm converting rails 4 app to rails 5. I'm having this error in Doorkeeper in creating token.

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)):
  app/controllers/oauth/tokens_controller.rb:4:in `create'


class Oauth::TokensController < Doorkeeper::TokensController
  def create
    response = authorize_response
    self.headers.merge! response.headers
    self.response_body =
      if response.status == :ok
        json_success( response )
      else
        json_fail( response )
      end
  end
```

end

everything is fine in rails 4.